# Trying ubuntu using a bootable USB and creating an account

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, usb

I want to create a bootable USB and have downloaded the ISO file and will create this on a 16GB San Disk USB drive.

I have read that you can create an account once you have inserted the USB and booted from it, then selected TRY UBUNTU.

Once this is done will it boot a viable operating system with login rather than selecting TRY UBUNTU each time or do I have to install to the USB drive?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

For this you need to install Ubuntu onto your USB stick. I'd use another stick as installer and physically unplug all hard drives if possible, just to prevent them from any harm. No you can install onto the USB stick you want to use (should be 8GB at least I think) as you would install on your computer.
I don't know any other way to install Ubuntu onto a stick. Maybe there's already an image for installation on USB sticks. Please correct my instructions if you find any mistakes...